# vscode warning for included js obj

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have 2 question about the edit visual studio code.
 1. when I include a js file in my html as `<script src="hey.js"></script>` and use it in my js code after like `hey.speak()` the editor says 'cannot find name 'hey'.

2. when I create new function and calling this function afterward when it shows me the function's argument why it says "any" on every argument it takes ? when In real the current function expects to get a function (in a callback case)

I'm trying to arrange my project code, and I'm trying to follow the wornings. thanks (:

Comment: You need to *show your code*. And I imagine it says any because it takes any variable type. Do you have any TypeScript in the project?

Comment: does foo.js have a function named "foo" inside it?

Comment: better yet, does `foo.js` have a variable/object called `foo` with a function called `bar` in it?

Comment: Visual Studio Code uses the TypeScript interpreter behind the scenes to validate all JavaScript.  https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages  "Visual Studio Code uses the TypeScript brain to make authoring JavaScript easy. In addition to syntactical features like format, format on type, outlining, etc., Visual Studio Code also offers some degree of semantic validation and understanding."

Comment: the question was edited by a failure guy who ruined it's point.
anyway, my question is if I include the `hey.js` file (which has inside `var hey = new hey();`) why vscode show a warning on this one saying "'cannot find name 'hey'" how should I declare it ?

Answer (score 1):

VSCode doesn't load `<script>` tags referenced in HTML automatically. If you open the referenced file by yourself (e.g. in an editor to the side), global symbols should get picked up.

This is definitely a nice feature request, you can ask for it at the [VSCode User Voice Website](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code).

In the meantime, you can configure the [linting settings of JavaScript](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages#_javascript), to ignore `undeclaredVariables`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to include

```
/* global hey */
```

to the top of your script, then VS Code (and  other linters) will know that you have an undeclared global the you will be importing.